# R: Create a markdown report for multiple vectors in a loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, r-markdown

Everyone,

I have a report I am creating in RMarkdown that will create the same report with same format based off of different data points.

I have a data frame (df1) like below and use select vectors to use in my markdown report.

```
PARK    WTG      FEONOFF        CODE    TEXT                         FMcount
MOZART  82262    FE_FM1667    FM1667    PIT Critical I2t Sum Max        187
MOZART  82257    FE_FM1667    FM1667    PIT Critical I2t Sum Max        61
BEEBE   82314    FE_FM500     FM500     Wind SpeedDiff multiple         10
```

Then I am running the below script to pull out each row and get my data vectors for my markdown report, and then create and save my report to my directory.

```
require(data.table)
SiWTG <-c()
for (i in 1:length(df1)) { 
SW <- data.table(df1[i,])
SW <- data.table(SW)
SWTG <- data.table(unlist(SW[1]))
WTG <- as.numeric(SWTG[2])     #use this vector in markdown report
CODE <- as.character(SWTG[5])  #use this vector in markdown report

render("markdownCSS.rmd", output_file = "markdownReport.html")

SiWTG <- SW
}
```

My markdown report will run internal queries from the two listed vectors. These vectors are used to fill out data to be printed in the report.

Now the above script will run through df1, list and only create the markdown report for the last row, for that each row overwrites the one prior.

So, what I would like to have the loop run through the data frame and create a markdown report for each row. The title of each `output_file = "markdownReport.html"` would need to be different so that I have three separate reports.

I would like to us each item in WTG column, and input into the markdown report title like this.

```
82262markdownReport.html
82257markdownReport.html
82314markdownReport.html
```

This way I would have 3 separate markdown reports saved on my computer.

Comment: You can pass a list of parameters as `rmarkdown::render(.., params=list(...))`, which can be used by the RMarkdown file as `params$...`. See https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports and https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-6.html

Comment: Simply `paste0` the *WTG* variable to the output file name: `output_file = paste0(WTG, "markdownReport.html")`.

Comment: Thanks guys, something as simple as a `paste0` i didn't think of. Also the links will be great to read up on too.